# Entityform: email submitted form to someone who is not admin?

Tags: entities

How do I get the [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module to email the contents of a submitted form to user@example.com. The owner of this email address is not the admin. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

go to admin/config/workflow/entity_rules/entityform_submission and clone "Entityform Notification Email Submitter" or "Entityform Notification Email Admin", edit accordingly. If that does not works, please add a custom rule (admin/config/workflow/rules):

event: After saving a new entityform submission
Condition: Entity has field: [entityform], Field: token of your field
Action: send email, use the token for your email field or any email you want.

Comment: I used rules to implement the custom confirmation emails, not the entityform rules. Thanks.